# Unit testing custom validator of command object with dependency

Tags: unit-testing, grails, service, constraints

I have a command object for registering user, and I want to check how old is the user. This command object has a service dependency. How can I test custom validator for my dateOfBirth property? As it looks now is taken straight from documentation, [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.10%20Command%20Objects).

```
class RegisterUserCommand {

  def someService

  String username
  String password
  String password2
  String email
  Date dateOfBirth

  static constraints = {
    // other constraints
    dateOfBirth blank: false, validator: {val, obj ->
      return obj.someService.calculateAge(val) >= 18
    }
  }
```

So basically the question is: how can I mock 'obj' parameter of the validator closure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to test validation on a command object is to use [`GrailsUnitTestCase.mockForConstraintsTests`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/GrailsUnitTestCase.html#mockForConstraintsTests%28java.lang.Class,%20java.util.List%29).  A mock validate method will be applied to your command object, and you can just call `validate()` like you would outside of a test.

Here's an example of how you could write your unit test.  The `blank` constraint isn't meaningful for dates, so I've changed it to `nullable: false`.

```
import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase

class RegisterUserCommandTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    RegisterUserCommand cmd

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        cmd = new RegisterUserCommand()
        mockForConstraintsTests RegisterUserCommand, [cmd]
    }

    void testConstraintsNull() {
        cmd.dateOfBirth = null
        cmd.someService = [calculateAge: { dob -> 18 }]
        def result = cmd.validate()
        assert result == false
        assert cmd.errors.getFieldErrors('dateOfBirth').code ==  ['nullable']
    }

    void testConstraintsCustom() {
        cmd.dateOfBirth = new Date()
        cmd.someService = [calculateAge: { dob -> 17 }]
        def result = cmd.validate()
        assert result == false
        assert cmd.errors.getFieldErrors('dateOfBirth').code == ['validator.invalid']
    }
}
```

Note that your service won't get injected in a unit test (it *will* in an integration test though), so you'll either need to mock it, as above, or create an instance and assign it to `cmd.someservice`.

Comment: Didn't think about mocking command objects for constraint tests :) It solved the case.